# How to dynamically add elements to String array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I want to add dynamic number of elements to a string array from inside a for loop.

How to create an string array of an undefined length?

Comment: ArrayList = dynamic array

Answer (score 131, accepted):

`Arrays` in Java have a defined size, you cannot change it later by adding or removing elements (you can read some basics [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)).

Instead, use a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html):

```
ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
mylist.add(mystring); //this adds an element to the list.
```

Of course, if you know beforehand how many strings you are going to put in your array, you can create an array of that size and set the elements by using the correct position:

```
String[] myarray = new String[numberofstrings];
myarray[23] = string24; //this sets the 24'th (first index is 0) element to string24.
```

Answer (score 31):

when using String array, you have to give size of array while initializing

eg

```
String[] str = new String[10];
```

you can use index 0-9 to store values

```
str[0] = "value1"
str[1] = "value2"
str[2] = "value3"
str[3] = "value4"
str[4] = "value5"
str[5] = "value6"
str[6] = "value7"
str[7] = "value8"
str[8] = "value9"
str[9] = "value10"
```

if you are using ArrayList instread of string array, you can use it without initializing size of array
   ArrayList str = new ArrayList();

you can add value by using **add** method of Arraylist

```
str.add("Value1");
```

get retrieve a value from arraylist, you can use **get** method

```
String s = str.get(0);
```

find total number of items by **size** method

```
int nCount = str.size();
```

read more from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 3):

You cant add add items in string array more than its size, i'll suggest you to use **ArrayList**
you can add  items dynamically at run time in arrayList
if you feel any problem you can freely ask