# Making a String containing the same character multiple times

Tags: java, string

How can I initialize a String with dynamic length in Java?

For example, I want to have a String consisting of *n* characters `a`, where *n* is a variable. Can I do that?

Comment: Ummmm say again?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039519/how-to-dynamically-add-elements-to-string-array

Answer (score 5):

You can use StringBuilder and define a method called e.g. getString.

```
public static String getString(char ch, int n){ 
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(n);
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
           sb.append(ch);
        }
        String s = sb.toString();
        return s;
}
```

Now you can make some calls to this method.

```
String sA1 = getString('a', 10);
String sA2 = getString('a', 20);
String sB = getString('b', 30);
String sC = getString('c', 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String myChar = "a";
int n = 10;
for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
   sb.append(myChar);
}

String myResult = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays have a fixed length in Java. If you want the size to be dynamic, you need to use a List object

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Have a look at the [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) documentation.

And if you need array then

```
String[] stringArray = stringList .toArray(new String[stringList .size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

String is immutable. When you are initializing a string it is once. you cant change its size time to time. the size should n`t be dynamic.

Use other option like StringBuilder to do this

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
  strB.append("a");
}

String str = strB.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

```
ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
mylist.add(mystring); //this adds an element to the list.
```