# Array on a SharedPreference (FIFO)

Tags: android, arrays, sharedpreferences, storage

I want to make a progress graph on which the player will see his latest 5 game history score. My problem here is I would want to save it on a `SharedpPeference` the latest 5 game's score then transfer it in Addition `Array`. which would be like this :

```
int[] x = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
int[] Addition = new int [x.length];
```

is it possible with `SharedPreference`? And how do I make it in a FIFO way? Because I just need only the latest 5 game's score? Can someone help me on this kind of logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't store `Arrays` in `SharedPreferences`.

You could store a pref called `scores` that is a `String`. Then, inside of that, store each game with an `int`.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPrefs("score");
```

then when you create your `Editor` to save the scores create each one

```
Editor ed = prefs.edit();
ed.putInt("1", scoreOneVar);
ed.commit;
```

Then when there is a sixth game you would need to remove the first one or use an algorithm to just get the last 5.

**However**, storing/retrieving these in a DB or a file would probably be better/easier.

[See the docs about storage options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: is there any chance that I can do it on a sharedpreference? because SQlite is more complicated.

Comment: Just the way I showed above. Store them as separate files. I only added the first score but then you could add a second the same way with a `"2", scoreTwoVar`. But an SQLite DB really isn't that complicated once you try one.

Comment: Thanks for the idea sir. You guys really help me. I just then need to learn the algorithm for the FiFO.

Comment: Start with what you've learned so far then do some research. If you are still stuck after that, then post a new question with the details.

Comment: sir is it possible to use an integer array for this one?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
int x[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
String willSave = "";
for(int i=0 ; i<x.length ; i++){
    willSave += String.valueOf(x[i]) + ";";
}

saveString(getBaseContext(), "Values", "LastScores", willSave);

// Checking the last cached values      
String cachedValues = loadString(getBaseContext(), "Values", "LastScores");
String splitted[] = cachedValues.split(";");

int lastValues[] = new int[splitted.length];
for(int i=0 ; i<splitted.length ; i++){
    lastValues[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitted[i]);
}
```

The functions `saveString` and `loadString`:

```
public void saveString(Context c, String prefName, String key, String value){
    SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(prefName, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit(); 
}

public String loadString(Context c, String prefName, String key){
    SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(prefName, 0);
    return new String(settings.getString(key, ""));
}
```

**This codes do that:** Firstly converts your `int` array to `String`, because you can not save arrays to sharedPrefs. Then converts this cached `String` to `int` array again.

Comment: Explaining *how* and *why* your code should solve the problem is much more beneficial than slapping down a wall of code.

Comment: I thought that he/she can understand it by only reading the codes. There is not much code. Anyway, i added a little explanation.

Comment: It's not just about the OP understanding but to help future visitors with a similar problem. Anyway, if someone doesn't know how to do something, hence asking here, then there's a good chance that an explanation of how/why the code works is very beneficial to everyone...even yourself.

Comment: Yes, you are right, i understand and added. If you want to add something too or the explanation is not enough for understand, you can edit sir. Thanks

Comment: thanks for the help. I really appreciate it sir. By the way assume that variable `scoreValue` holds the value of the score that I want to insert as the element of the array. where and how do I do that?

Comment: You should more google then, you can not insert a value to array. You can use `ArrayList`, check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039519/how-to-dynamically-add-elements-to-string-array)

Comment: sir is it possible to use an integer array to this?